# VirtualBox memory exception - std::bad_alloc using TensorFlow and Docker

Tags: python, docker, virtualbox, tensorflow

I have a Python application where I'm using TensorFlow and I'm running it inside of a Docker container. When running locally I see the memory usage stay well under 4GB of Ram, but there are some large files being written and processed. When TensorFlow reaches the point of creating its first checkpoint file I get the following exception:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

My model is complex so this file may be above 1GB, but also my data is images so I've already downloaded about 30GB of data just to begin running the model so I don't know if it's just by chance this keeps happening here or if this file actually happens to be too large. I'm only loading a small batch of images into memory for model training per epoch so I'm trying to keep the RAM usage low. My VirtualBox config looks like so:

[image]

The error appears to be using C++ so I assume it's coming from TensorFlow code internally. Has anyone seen anything like this or know what I can change? I feel that there is enough RAM allocated but maybe my disk access isn't configured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not enough RAM.  4GB is very small for running TensorFlow (particularly in python with a default install) for training.  Your model size may well be below 1GB, but during training - and when writing out a checkpoint - TensorFlow will temporarily allocate more memory for buffering, and that's probably where you're getting an OOM error.  If you run fine normally with 4GB until checkpointing, 8GB should be fine.